# Writing webmock stubs on Modules specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, wrapper, webmock

My problem is I'm creating a wrapper to deal with a connection to an external server (GeoNetwork) and treat its response.

While I had my request in my Search Controller, it was working fine. Then I tried to follow this solution for the wrapper:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd--net-23875

But now, I'm having an error on webmock that I can't figure out why.

### ../lib/wrapper/api.rb

```
module Wrapper
  class Api
    class << self
      attr_accessor :base_uri
    end

    include HTTP

    @base_uri = 'http://boldo.caiena.net:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/'

    builder_for_summary = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml['csw'].GetRecords('xmlns:csw' => 'http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2',
                            'service' => 'CSW',
                            'version' => '2.0.2',
                            'resultType' => 'results',
                            # metadata records start at position 1
                            'startPosition' => '1',
                            'maxRecords' => '10') do
        xml['csw'].Query('typeNames' => 'gmd:MD_Metadata') {
          xml['csw'].Constraint('version' => '1.1.0'){
            xml.Filter('xmlns' => 'http://www.opengis.net/ogc',
                       'xmlns:gml' => 'http://www.opengis.net/gml'){
              xml.PropertyIsLike('wildCard' => '',
                              'singleChar' => '_'){
                xml.PropertyName 'any'
                xml.Literal ''    #params[:search_field]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      end
    end

   response = HTTP.post("#{@base_uri}csw", body: builder_for_summary.to_xml)
                  .with_headers(content_type: "application/xml")
                  .response
  end
end
```

---

### ../spec/lib/api_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Wrapper::Api do

  it 'should work' do
    expect('Yay!').to be_an_instance_of String
  end

  describe 'default attributes' do
    it 'should include http methods' do
      expect(Wrapper::Api).to include HTTP
    end

    it 'should have the base url set to the GeoNetwork API endpoint' do
      expect(Wrapper::Api.base_uri).to eq('http://boldo.caiena.net:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/')
    end
  end

  describe 'request' do
    it 'makes a request to GeoNetwork' do
      WebMock.should have_requested(:post, "#{Wrapper::Api.base_uri}csw")
    end
  end
end
```

---

### ../spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require_relative '../config/environment'
require_relative '../lib/wrapper'

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'webmock/rspec'

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    support_path = 'spec/support/fixtures/'
    url = 'http://boldo.caiena.net:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/'
    canned_request = File.read "#{support_path}request_all_metadata.xml"
    canned_response = File.read "#{support_path}all_metadata_results.xml"

    stub_request(:post, "#{url}csw")
    .with(header:'application/xml')
    .to_return(body: canned_response)

  end

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures

  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  # Enabling FactoryGirl methods with ease
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

---

### The error I'm getting is:

```
/Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/webmock-1.17.4/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/http_gem_adapter.rb:125:in `halt': Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST http://boldo.caiena.net:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw with body '<?xml version="1.0"?> (WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError)
<csw:GetRecords xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" service="CSW" version="2.0.2" resultType="results" startPosition="1" maxRecords="10">
  <csw:Query typeNames="gmd:MD_Metadata">
    <csw:Constraint version="1.1.0">
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <PropertyIsLike wildCard="" singleChar="_">
          <PropertyName>any</PropertyName>
          <Literal/>
        </PropertyIsLike>
      </Filter>
    </csw:Constraint>
  </csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
' with headers {'Host'=>'boldo.caiena.net', 'User-Agent'=>'RubyHTTPGem/0.5.0'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:post, "http://boldo.caiena.net:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw").
  with(:body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<csw:GetRecords xmlns:csw=\"http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2\" service=\"CSW\" version=\"2.0.2\" resultType=\"results\" startPosition=\"1\" maxRecords=\"10\">\n  <csw:Query typeNames=\"gmd:MD_Metadata\">\n    <csw:Constraint version=\"1.1.0\">\n      <Filter xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/ogc\" xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\">\n        <PropertyIsLike wildCard=\"\" singleChar=\"_\">\n          <PropertyName>any</PropertyName>\n          <Literal/>\n        </PropertyIsLike>\n      </Filter>\n    </csw:Constraint>\n  </csw:Query>\n</csw:GetRecords>\n",
       :headers => {'Host'=>'boldo.caiena.net', 'User-Agent'=>'RubyHTTPGem/0.5.0'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

============================================================
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/webmock-1.17.4/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/http_gem_adapter.rb:76:in `exec'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/webmock-1.17.4/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/http_gem_adapter.rb:146:in `perform'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/http-0.5.0/lib/http/client.rb:58:in `request'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/http-0.5.0/lib/http/chainable.rb:50:in `request'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/http-0.5.0/lib/http/chainable.rb:15:in `post'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper/api.rb:34:in `<class:Api>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper/api.rb:2:in `<module:Wrapper>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper/api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper.rb:3:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/lib/wrapper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/Workspace/copernico-ide/copernico/spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/thiagoalves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@copernico/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

---